# Default values not working Ruby On Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Initially i had `<%= @place.vicinity ||= @place.location.display_address[0] %>` but it threw error

> undefined method `vicinity' for <
>   BurstStruct::Burst:0x00000006126ff0>

I tried with only `||` also and with `@place.vicinity.present?` also but the same error .when i echos my `@place.location.display_address[0]`, it is present . so i thought that may be due to non presence of `vicinity` member in the class it's throwing error ( despite i've tested it with `nil?` operator also) then i tried the `ternary oprator` like below and still the same error :/
    `<%= @place.vicinity.nil? ? @place.location.display_address[0] :@place.vicinity  %>`

 any help and suggestion will be appreciated

**Update** 
What i'm doing actually that When i call for the yelp it returns me location and when i call Google i return "vicinity" - so no classes

**Controller**

```
def index
  phone_number =params["phone_number"]
  if params["provider"] == 'GOOGLE'
    client = GooglePlaces::Client.new("Qf4D-GJpap09o")
    @place =  client.spot(params["place_id"])  
  elsif params["provider"] == 'yelp'
    yelp_client = Yelp::client 
    @place = yelp_client.business(params["place_id"])   
  end
end
```

Comment: post your code of `vicinity` method. Have you defined it?

Comment: it's dynamic member of `@place`

Comment: Could you update your question with `BurstStruct::Burst` structure? Thanks

Comment: Dear it's rails built in class - plus if i'm using nil? operator then it should not look into vicinity if vicinity is not present

Comment: In your case `vicinity` not exists. You're calling a method that is not present for the class  `BurstStruct::Burst`, doesn't matter its value. Please check the class or give us more codes to evaluate.

Comment: What is @place being set to in the controller? And could you post the code for the model that this is an instance of?

Comment: @MichaelCruz see my updates

Comment: So where is the @place instance variable being set? That's the code I'm asking to see.

Comment: @MichaelCruz mentioned the controller code

Comment: It looks to me like the if and elsif are both failing and @place isn't being set. Use the pry gem or something similar, and set a call to binding.pry at the beginning of the index action. Then see what the value of params["provider"] is there. Let me know via update or comment.

Answer (score 3):

The error is due to the missing of the instance method `vicinity` for the object `@place`.

`@place.vicinity` raise an exception before, so the operator `||` or the method `.nil?` are not executed.

In response of your comment, if you want to know if the method vicinity exists you could with `try` method:

```
klass.try(:vicinity)
```

It checks for the existence of the method and execute it if exists, otherwhise returns `nil` if it doesn't.

References: 
http://apidock.com/rails/Object/try

Comment: I know but then what is use of `nil?` or `||` operator

Comment: you mean `@place.vicinity.nil?` is not gonna work ? then mention the way we can check for its `nil`

Comment: Or, if you're living on the edge (Ruby 2.3), you do: `@place&.vicinity`. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Above answer from NickGnd looks good, but just wanted to throw in that `||` is more appropriate than `||=` here for a default value. `||=` does variable assignment as well, meaning if `@place.vicinity` returns nil, `#vicinity=` (setter/mutator) will also need to be a method known by `@place`. And beyond that (I'm assuming based on the ERB tags that this is in a view), you usually want to do variable assignment in a controller before the view is rendered.